# How to solve this absolute value inequality?

Tags: inequality

I am new to absolute value inequalities.I was looking trough a book and I found this inequality,
I know a little bit about absolute value inequalities.
The inequality is given below:

$$
\left| \frac{n+1}{2n+3} - \frac{1}{2} \right| > \frac{1}{12}, \qquad n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is an absolute value

**Case 1)**

$$\frac{n+1}{2n+3} - \frac{1}{2} > \frac{1}{12} $$

**Case 2)**

$$\frac{n+1}{2n+3} - \frac{1}{2} < \frac{-1}{12}$$

Now I can solve it a little for you , as in Case 1

$$\frac{n+1}{2n+3} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{12}>0 $$

$$\frac{n+1}{2n+3} - \frac{7}{12} >  0 $$

Comment: That is what i did ,after that I added 7/12 to both sides and then it gave me this,12n+12>14n+21 so i subtracted 14n and i got  -2n>9 so then n<-9/2

Comment: Should I write the next steps for the equation ?? If you want

Comment: :) I can explain it to you further :_

Comment: sorry,i edited the comment,as I said I already did this but it gave me n<-9/2 and n<3/2

Comment: @KartikBhatia This way works but it is not much effective. As first step it is convenient reduce the expression inside the absolut evalue and then consider the cases or expand directly the inequality.

Comment: By efficient do you mean that I will not get the right answer?

Comment: So what do I do if it gives me n<-9/2 and n<3/2? Do I do the intersection of the intervals?

Comment: Yes I prefer to draw a numberline and then choose the integer solutions , it is better working this way out with intervals

Comment: Ok, I am in 9 grade and I have done these type of inequatities before but then it gave solutions like 3<n<4 and i just wrote n belongs to (3,4) but it never gave me something like n<-9/2 and n<3/2 so i did not know what to do

Comment: you are doing good work that you are :) studying some good topics in 9th grade itself , You have any more doubts now ?

Comment: No ,thank you,for everything!

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\left|\frac{n+1}{2n+3}-\frac12\right|=\left|\frac{-1}{2(2n+3)}\right| =\frac{1}{|2(2n+3)|}>\frac1{12}\iff |2n+3|<6 $$

$$\iff -6<2n+3<6 \iff -9<2n<3 \iff -\frac92<n<\frac32$$

that is $n\in\{-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1\}$.

Answer (score 2):

First simplify the expression inside the absolute value:
$$\left|\frac{n+1}{2n+3}-\frac12\right|=\left|\frac{-1}{4n+6}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{4n+6}\right|>\frac1{12}$$

Now take the reciprocal of both sides:
$$|4n+6|<12$$

and this can be interpreted as:

$$-12 < 4n + 6 < 12$$

then finish the rest.

Comment: I did not simplify so it gave me n<3/2 and n<-9/2

Comment: so i do the intersection of (-infinite,3/2) and (-infinite,-9/2)?

Comment: You should get $n > -\frac92$.

Answer (score 2):

As $2n+3\ne0$,

$$\left|\frac{n+1}{2n+3}-\frac12\right|>\frac1{12}$$

can be written (multiplying by $12|2n+3|$)

$$6>|2n+3|.$$

The odd numbers below $6$ are $1,3,5$ (in absolute value), from which we draw

$$n=-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1.$$

---

As the number of solutions is small, I preferred to exhaust them rather than work out the inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

For case 1:

$ \frac{n+1}{2n+3} - \frac{1}{2} > \frac{1}{12} $

$ \frac{n+1}{2n+3} - \frac{2n+3}{2(2n+3)} > \frac{1}{12} $

$ \frac{-1}{2(2n+3)} > \frac{1}{12} $

$ \frac{-6}{2n+3} > 1 $

$ \Rightarrow 2n+3 < 0 $ and $ 2n+3 > -6 $

$ \frac{-9}{2} > n < \frac{-3}{2} $